# Google Sheets - Filtering out values in a range from another range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

-- EDIT #2 -- Updated the Google Sheet again with a solution which is painfully close. Best formula I've had so far is below. --

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(UNIQUE({ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF(COUNTIF(G4:G&"|||"&H4:H,ARRAYFORMULA(A4:A&"|||"&B4:B))>0,REGEXREPLACE(A4:A&"|||"&B4:B,".*",""),A4:A&"|||"&B4:B),"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"));ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF(COUNTIF(G4:G&"|||"&H4:H,ARRAYFORMULA(D4:D&"|||"&E4:E))>0,REGEXREPLACE(D4:D&"|||"&E4:E,".*",""),D4:D&"|||"&E4:E),"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"))}),"|||"))
```

-- EDIT -- Updated the Google Sheet to more closely reflect my use case --

Pretty confident someone's asked this before but I've been Googling for a few hours now and I'm starting to lose hair. I think I've got to use a QUERY function but not 100% on that.

**Demo sheet here:** https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p_hqk9WydcyXQZT4bIm4DSZZnaPKbngtnZ0-laYHwk8/edit?usp=sharing

**What I want to do:**
I want to combine the ranges under *DATA 1* and *DATA 2*, but I want to exclude and rows which start with the values in *DATA 3*.

*RESULT 1* doesn't add value but shows how I was adding *DATA 1* and *DATA 2* together.

*RESULT 2* shows the result I'm trying to get.

*RESULT 3* hidden but where I got to (and doesn't add value again, sorry). I can get it mostly working, but I'd have to manually specify in the QUERY which combinations I'm looking for... and frankly my dataset is HUGE. That formula currently looks like this:

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE({FILTER(A4:B,NOT(ISBLANK(A4:A)));FILTER(D4:E,NOT(ISBLANK(D4:D)))}),"SELECT * WHERE NOT Col1 STARTS WITH 'a' OR NOT Col2 STARTS WITH 'v'",-1)
```

Hope someone can help me out! You're my only hope.

Comment: Would a custom function written in Apps Script be a suitable solution for you?

Comment: I'm always keen to stick to formulas where possible, but if it makes a solution far easier I'm more than happy to go with Apps Script. Feel pretty comfortable with it generally speaking.

Comment: I've got a partial solution but it's not quite there. The wildcards within my COUNTIF isn't working well though. Has anyone got a solution for this? =ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(UNIQUE({ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF(COUNTIF(G4:G&"|||"&H4:H,ARRAYFORMULA(A4:A&"|||"&B4:B))>0,REGEXREPLACE(A4:A&"|||"&B4:B,".*",""),A4:A&"|||"&B4:B),"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"));ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF(COUNTIF(G4:G&"|||"&H4:H,ARRAYFORMULA(D4:D&"|||"&E4:E))>0,REGEXREPLACE(D4:D&"|||"&E4:E,".*",""),D4:D&"|||"&E4:E),"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"))}),"|||"))

Answer (score 1):

This works for your example data. It uses `ARRAYFORMULA` and `MATCH` to concatenate the two columns and `LEFT` to only use the first character in the match function. You might need to find a slightly smarter way to do the *starts with* element depending on your actual data.

`=UNIQUE({FILTER(A4:B,not(isblank(A4:A)),iserror(MATCH(ARRAYFORMULA(A4:A&left(B4:B,1)),ARRAYFORMULA(G4:G&H4:H),0)));FILTER(D4:E,not(isblank(D4:D)),iserror(MATCH(ARRAYFORMULA(D4:D&left(E4:E,1)),ARRAYFORMULA(G4:G&H4:H),0)))})`

Documentation:

`MATCH`: [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en)

`ARRAYFORMULA`: [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)

Comment: This seems like a good step forward. Is there a way REGEXMATCH could be incorporated to perform the "STARTS WITH" function?

Comment: That's not out of the question. I don't know though if the arrayformulas affect it

Comment: I've updated my question @a-burge - any idea how the wildcard within COUNTIF might work better?

Answer (score 0):

Was also looking for how to find the set-difference between two ranges.
All my values were in one range but I reworked my solution to fit your case of needing to join ranges too.

**Finding the set-difference between two ranges:**

```
// given A1:A9 and C1:C9
// return all values in A1:A10 excluding those in C1:C10
=filter(A1:A9, not(iferror( match(A1:A9,C1:C9,0), false )), A1:A9<>"")
```

**Finding the set-difference between two joined ranges and a third range:**

```
// given A1:A9, B1:B9, and C1:C9
// return all values in A1:A10 and B1:B10 excluding those in C1:C10
=filter({A1:A9;B1:B9}, not(iferror( match({A1:A9;B1:B9},C1:C9,0), false )), {A1:A9;B1:B9}<>"")
```

Breakdown:

*Goal is to get an output range that is the input range excluding all values in an "exclusion" range*

[`MATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en): match all values that are in both your input range and your exclusion range (remaining values will produce an error)

[`NOT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093305?hl=en) + [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304) : convert matches to false and errors to true

[`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en): filter the input down to only the true values (i.e. whats *not* matched, a.k.a. remove the excluded values), and also add a 2nd condition to remove blanks

tips:

`{X;Y}`: unions two ranges, `;` adds rows `,` adds columns

`X<>""`: true for all non-blank values in range X